# Duplicated options are wrongly accepted in Apache Commons Cli

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

When I repeat some options by command line are wrongly accepted

```
private static void buildMyCliOptions() { 
   optionsMyAdd.addOption(Option.builder()
     .longOpt("my-address")
     .argName("property=value")
     .hasArg()
     .desc("Specify Address")
     .required()
     .build());

   optionsMyAdd.addOption(Option.builder()
     .longOpt("my-port")
     .argName("property=value") 
     .hasArgs()
     .valueSeparator()
     .desc("Specify port")
     .required()
     .build());

} 

tempOptions = ParseCommand.getOptionsMyAdd();
commandLine = cmdLineParser.parse(tempOptions, ParseCommand.args,true);
```

for instance: `add --my-address=addr1 --my-address=addr2 --my-port=port1`

But I would like an error for `--my-address=addr2`, since it is duplicated.

Comment: I think that it is a feature to allow duplicates, so if you want some error handling then you need to add it yourself

Comment: @JoakimDanielson there are already too many things to add. I would understand now the added value to use Commns Cli.

Comment: Any other hint?

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my previous comment but I don't think there is any why to get the Commons CLI to generate an error, if you consider a duplicate to be wrong then you have to perform the check and generate the error in your code.